# HMAC equivalent in C# with chr(0) in byte array?

Tags: c#, php, hash

I am having a problem getting the equivalent to hash the same in C# as php:

$sig = hash_hmac('sha512', $endpoint . chr(0) . $data, $password);

I think the problem is in the way php builds the string with the chr(0).

In C# i need a byte array with equivalent of chr(0) in between $endpoint and $password..

hmacsha512.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(endPoint + (char)0 + password)) not working.

Comment: *not working* -- what does it mean?

Comment: Hi, my problem is in c# trying to build the equivalent string: in php it's - $endpoint . chr(0) . $data .. and in C# it's?

Comment: Can you post your *actual* code please?  The code you posted is invalid and incomplete - we have no idea which encoding you're using, you are putting the password in the string you're hashing, etc.